# Запаковать данные для работы программы в архив

Tags: c#, winforms, хранение-данных, архивация

Изучаю C# и сразу пишу музыкальный плеер (Для тренировки сам себе придумал такое вот задание). У меня для кнопок используются картинки, которых очень много. Картинки для каждой кнопки в отдельных папках. Как реализовать следующее: создать архив, например с расширением .data, в котором будут данные папки с картинками и от туда будут браться картинки для кнопок при работе программы? Ну и желательно что бы данный архив нельзя было открыть архиватором WinRar. Расскажите подробнее как такое реализовывается и если можно дайте пример.

Comment: Зачем это? Ресурсы использовать никак?

Comment: @AGS17 у меня получается более 200 картинок и очень много других файлов. Хочется упорядочить их таким образом, что бы в будущем можно было легко работать с ними. 
А как работают ресурсы? не нужно будет хранить картинки и файлы в папке с программой?

Comment: Используй установочник какой-нибудь

Comment: @Alex78191 что значит "установочник какой нибудь?"

Comment: Можешь resx использовать

Comment: [System.IO.Compression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.compression(v=vs.110).aspx) для сжатия, [System.Security.Cryptography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx) для шифрования.

Answer (score 1):

Если хочется, чтобы никто не смог вытащить инфу из твоего файла, то придумай свой формат, в котором будешь хранить свои бинарные данные. Теоретически, очень сложно вытащить данные из такого файла, но умельцы всегда найдутся. Но это всё трата времени и сил. Есть стандартные средства для хранения картинок в WinForms, AGS17 предложил вам хранить это в ресурсах.